# How to add current session id with link/download link?

Tags: php, session

I'm not sure but how to simply add current session id with a link/download links ?

```
<?php if($images) { $i=0; for ($index = 0; $index < count($images); $index++){ $i++ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $images[$index]; ?>">Download</a><br/> 
<?php }}?>
```

Comment: Use [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

Comment: I want to know how? please add example. @AaronW.

Comment: `<?php echo $images[$index] . '?' . session_name() . '=' . session_id(); ?>` or  `<?php echo $images[$index] . '?' . SID; ?>`

Comment: I don't understand bro. I'm not developer. Please add full example/answer. @RaymondNijland

Comment: @Mozz I suggest adding more of your code. The answers provided are clear and should work. If you don't know how to concat strings then there are bigger problems.

Comment: Sorry @AaronW. i got it... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
<?php if($images) { $i=0; for ($index = 0; $index < count($images); $index++){ $i++ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $images[$index] . '?PHPSESSID=' . session_id(); ?>">Download</a><br/> 
<?php }}?>
```